# сортировка строк без учета верхнего регистра букв

Tags: c++, алгоритм, сортировка, строки, stl

Задача в следующем - отсортировать контейнер со строками без учета верхнего регистра букв в алфавитном порядке, например:

```
std::vector<std::string> strList = {"Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma", "aaa", "bbb", "ccc"};
```

Если применить алгоритм сортировки:

```
std::sort(strList.begin(), strList.end());
```

Результат будет таким:

1) "Alpha"

2) "Beta"

3) "Gamma"

4) "aaa"

5) "bbb"

6) "ccc"

А я хочу без учета верхнего регистра букв:

1) "aaa"

2) "Alpha"

3) "bbb"

4) "Beta"

5) "ccc"

6) "Gamma"

Собственно интересует вопрос есть ли готовые алгоритмы для такого вида сортировок? Или нужно изобретать велосипед?

Comment: думаю нет, но можно написать компаратор bool cmp(string &a, string &b){ return tolower(a)<tolower(b) };

Comment: @pavel - вроде я видел готовые алгоритмы для сравнения, сейчас попробую

Comment: хотелось бы, всё же memcmp работает на ассемблерном уровне, самописные медленнее будут.

Answer (score 4):

Используйте компаратор, который будет сравнивать строки без учета регистра:

```
auto cmp = [](const std::string& a, const std::string& b) {
  return boost::ilexicographical_compare(a, b);
};
std::sort(begin(strList), end(strList), cmp);
```

Comment: а есть вне буста что-то такое?) а то либу тянуть здоровую ради такой мелочи как-то не красиво.

Answer (score 3):

Получился такой такой вариант - довольно колхозный и медленный, пожалуйста у кого есть мысли с лучшем вариантом - не стесняемся - выкладываем:

```
std::vector<std::string> strList = {куча строк}

std::sort(proc.begin(), proc.end(), [&](const std::string& elem1, const std::string& elem2) {return strcmpi(elem1.c_str(), elem2.c_str()) < 0; });
```

Comment: а оно вообще работает?

Comment: Я может не очень программист, но меня всегда интересовало в чём преимущество конструкции `if (strnicmp(p, p2, 10)<0) a = true; else a = false;` перед `a = strnicmp(p, p2, 10) < 0` ?..

Comment: @pavel - да работает отлично - проверено лично

Comment: А меня смущает константа 10. Почему бы сразу strcmpi() не использовать?

Comment: @Alekcvp а меня больше тут переменная a смущает, почему сразу не сделать return strnicmp(p, p2, 10)<0;

Comment: @Abyx - код улучшил, так как выкладывал копипаст с другого ресурса и не успел доработать

Comment: Нет, просто я уже не в первый раз в разных языках встречаю такую конструкцию, вот и заинтересовался - может я чего-то важного не знаю?..

Comment: @Alekcvp пока bool b; if (b.toString().length() < 5) не пишут всё ок.

Answer (score 2):

Возможно не самый оптимальный, но рабочий вариант. Возможны оптимизации, связанные с многократным приведением одной и той же строки к lowercase в предикате

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class SortPredicate {
public:

    bool operator()(const std::string& lhs, const std::string& rhs) const {
        std::string lhcLower(lhs);
        std::string rhcLower(rhs);
        std::transform(lhs.begin(), lhs.end(), lhcLower.begin(), ::tolower);
        std::transform(rhs.begin(), rhs.end(), rhcLower.begin(), ::tolower);
        return lhcLower < rhcLower;
    }
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    std::vector<std::string> strVec = {"Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma", "aaa", "bbb", "ccc"};
    std::sort(strVec.begin(), strVec.end(), SortPredicate());

    for(const std::string& item : strVec) {
        std::cout << item << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

result:

```
aaa
Alpha
bbb
Beta
ccc
Gamma
```